# In an application server environment, should one prefer javax.sql.DataSource or javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc

[An existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506859/datasource-or-connectionpooldatasource-for-application-server-jdbc-resources) expresses something similar, but I want to call out a slightly different nuance here.

The basic question: All application servers give the ability to specify *both* the (standard) interface *and* the (vendor-supplied) implementation classes for a (little-d, little-s) data source when you define a connection pool.  If a vendor supplies an implementation for both a `ConnectionPoolDataSource` and a regular ol' `DataSource`, which one is to be preferred?

What about for vendor implementations that implement `DataSource`, `ConnectionPoolDataSource` and `XADataSource` in the same implementation class?

The documentation for `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` says, almost in total:

> A factory for PooledConnection objects. An object that implements this interface will typically be registered with a naming service that is based on the JavaTM Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI).

That's basically useless, but it is worth noting that `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` does not itself extend `javax.sql.DataSource`, which means that implementations of it need not provide a `getConnection()` method, which is the one most callers are accustomed to using.  This tells me that all application servers MUST either:

- wrap a `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` implementation with a `javax.sql.DataSource` implementation so that callers can use `javax.sql.DataSource#getConnection()`, or
- detect that a `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` implementation is *also* a `javax.sql.DataSource` implementation, and (somehow) trust that its `getConnection()` method will delegate to `getPooledConnection()` (how on earth would they do this?)

The documentation for `javax.sql.DataSource` says, in part:

> The DataSource interface is implemented by a driver vendor. There are three types of implementations:
>
> - Basic implementation -- produces a standard Connection object
> - Connection pooling implementation -- produces a Connection object that will automatically participate in connection pooling. This implementation works with a middle-tier connection pooling manager.
> - Distributed transaction implementation -- produces a Connection object that may be used for distributed transactions and almost always participates in connection pooling. This implementation works with a middle-tier transaction manager and almost always with a connection pooling manager.

This is also useless, and incorrect to boot (or at least underspecified: `javax.sql.DataSource` is also implemented by application server vendors, who must provide an implementation so that client code may (for example) inject a `javax.sql.DataSource` into their server-side code).  It also seems to imply that connection pooling might or might not be offered by any given `DataSource` implementation, which would make me wonder how an application server is supposed to tell when a connection pool is set up that has specified the `javax.sql.DataSource` interface (instead of the `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` interface).

**Note:** I am not looking for an answer here about How I Did This On Tomcat, or The Steps I Took On GlassFish That Worked For Me or anything of that nature.  I'm looking for an answer that refers back to the JDBC specification, or the Java EE specification, or a bug report, or something that indicates why these separate (unrelated!) interfaces exist, and how they are supposed to be unified or distinguished between on a generic Java EE application server that is therefore obligated to offer connection pooling.

Comment: +1 for the interesting and specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a `ConnectionPoolDataSource` directly, it is intended as a source for physical connections (aka `PooledConnection`s) that are then used by a `DataSource` that actually implements connection pooling. A `ConnectionPoolDataSource` should not actually implement pooling itself.

Such a DataSource is for example provided by your application server. It usually takes a JNDI url (or a direct reference) to the `ConnectionPoolDataSource`, and itself exposes the `DataSource` interface to hand out 'logical' connections.

`DataSource`s are discussed in [JDBC 4.1](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_1-mrel-spec/index.html) section 9.4:

> The DataSource interface [..] is the preferred approach to obtaining data source connections.

and

> A logical name is mapped to a DataSource object via a naming service that uses the Java Naming and Directory InterfaceTM (JNDI). The DataSource object, represents a physical data source and provides connections to that data source.

If we then look at the description of Connection Pooling (chapter 11) in the introduction specifies:

> the JDBC driver provides an implementation of ConnectionPoolDataSource that the **application server uses to build and manage** the connection pool.
>
> The algorithm used to manage the connection pool is implementation-specific and
>   varies with application servers. **The application server provides its clients with an
>   implementation of the DataSource** interface that makes connection pooling
>   transparent to the client. As a result, the client gets better performance and
>   scalability while using the same JNDI and DataSource APIs as before. *(emphasis mine)*

The interaction between the (AS) `DataSource` (hereafter: ASDS) and the (driver) `ConnectionPoolDataSource` (hereafter CPDS) is described in section 11.1 - 11.3. Section 11.3 specifically describes the interaction:

> The following sequence of steps outlines what happens when a JDBC
>   client requests a connection from a DataSource object that implements
>   connection pooling:
>
> - The client calls DataSource.getConnection.
> - The application server providing the DataSource implementation looks in its connection pool to see if there is a suitable
>     PooledConnection object — a physical database connection— available.
>     Determining the suitability of a given PooledConnection object may
>     include matching the client’s user authentication information or
>     application type as well as using other implementation-specific
>     criteria. The lookup method and other methods associated with managing
>     the connection pool are specific to the application server.
> - If there are no suitable PooledConnection objects available, the application server calls the
>     ConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection method to get a new
>     physical connection. The JDBC driver implementing
>     ConnectionPoolDataSource creates a new PooledConnection object and
>     returns it to the application server.
> - Regardless of whether the PooledConnection was retrieved from the pool or was newly created, the application server does some internal
>     bookkeeping to indicate that the physical connection is now in use.
> - The application server calls the method PooledConnection.getConnection to get a logical Connection object.
>     This logical Connection object is actually a “handle” to a physical
>     PooledConnection object, and it is this handle that is returned by the
>     DataSource.getConnection method when connection pooling is in effect.
> - The application server registers itself as a ConnectionEventListener by calling the method
>     PooledConnection.addConnectionEventListener. This is done so that the
>     application server will be notified when the PooledConnection object
>     is available for reuse.
> - The logical Connection object is returned to the JDBC client, which uses the same Connection API as in the basic DataSource case. Note
>     that the underlying PooledConnection object cannot be reused until the
>     client calls the method Connection.close.

The last item is not entirely true: an ASDS can forcibly close/invalidate the logical connection from a client by handing out a new `Connection` obtained from the same `PooledConnection` (see section 11.4).

Now to come to your question in the comment: Why does an AS allow you to specify both a `DataSource` and `ConnectionPoolDataSource` interface in the datasource configuration: The reference between the ASDS and CPDS is usually done through JNDI as well. This for example allows easy reconfiguration (switching the ASDS to a different underlying CPDS, or switching the ASDS to a normal, basic DataSource while still maintaining the config of the CPDS for example because it is also used by a different ASDS). See also section 11.5 of the JDBC spec:

> Deploying a DataSource object that implements connection pooling requires that both a client-visible DataSource object and an underlying ConnectionPoolDataSource object be registered with a JNDI-based naming service.

Comment: OK, we need to be excruciatingly precise here. If you are right, then all application server vendors got everything wrong, because they all let you specify the `javax.sql.*` interface your data source (little-d, little-s) can implement, and one of the valid choices on all application servers is `ConnectionPoolDataSource`. It is certainly true that in _client_ code you always use a `javax.sql.DataSource` to get a JDBC connection, but that is not what I'm talking about.

Comment: (Since I can't edit my prior comment...) Want to make sure you understand I'm not talking about using a `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` from within client code. I'm talking about setting up a data source (little-d, little-s) on the application server. All application servers at this point let me choose whether my driver should expose itself at data source setup time as a `javax.sql.DataSource` or a `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` or a `javax.sql.XADataSource`. I know when I should pick the latter. I am unsure how to choose between the first two, and there is no documentation to help.

Comment: I think unfortunately it does not. I appreciate the specification references, which seem to imply (but _still_ do not state explicitly) that when I am setting up a new little-d data source I should prefer a `ConnectionPoolDataSource` implementation if my driver offers it. Then unfortunately your last paragraph opens the question up again.

Comment: I am not sure how the last paragraph opens that question again. What the JDBC spec tries to convey with that paragraph is : 1) setup `ConnectionPoolDataSource` in JNDI, 2) setup (AS) `DataSource` in JNDI that uses the JNDI reference of the CPDS from step 1, and finally 3) use the ASDS from step 2 in your application. See for example [this blog](http://www.hildeberto.com/2010/02/creating-connection-pool-to-postgresql.html), specifically steps 5 (corresponds to my step 1), 10 (corresponds to my step 2) and 11 (corresponds almost to my step 3)

Comment: Thanks. Now we have steps we can talk about.

I am uninterested in the blog's step 10 (your step 2), because in GlassFish parlance that is creating a JDBC resource, which is separate from creating the connection pool. Furthermore, when creating a JDBC resource there is no option to pick a `javax.sql.*` interface.

Nor am I interested in blog step 11 (your step 3) as that's client code.

So I'm interested only in blog step 5 (your step 1). In the blog, he chose `ConnectionPoolDataSource` here, but he could have chosen `javax.sql.DataSource` instead. Why did he make the choice he did?

Comment: Ah, now I get what you mean. I'll dive into it and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to shed some light:
I'm using Postgres, and [the API doc from PGConnectionPoolDataSource](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGConnectionPoolDataSource.html) is quite clear for me:

```
public class PGConnectionPoolDataSource
extends org.postgresql.ds.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4ConnectionPoolDataSource
implements javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource
```

> PostgreSQL implementation of ConnectionPoolDataSource. The app server
>   or middleware vendor **should provide** a DataSource implementation that
>   takes advantage of this ConnectionPoolDataSource. If not, **you can use**
>   the PostgreSQL implementation known as PoolingDataSource, but that
>   **should only be used if** your server or middleware vendor does not
>   provide their own. Why? The server may want to reuse the same
>   Connection across all EJBs requesting a Connection within the same
>   Transaction, or provide other similar advanced features.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Do kindly read the conversation I had with Mark below, as things are still unclear from the application server vendor perspective.